# How to search an element in ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to find `car` element in ArrayList. The ArrayList data like this
`{ [1,mobile,5000]
   [2,car,50000]
   [3,bike,20000] }`

and classes are

```
//pro.java
import java.util.*;  
public class Pro{

private int id;
private String name;
private int price;

public String toString(){  
return id+" "+name+" "+price;  
} 
//getter & setter methods
}
```

and the search code is like this

```
//Product.java
System.out.println("enter name you want to search");
name = scanner.next();
Iterator it=al.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
 if(it.next() == name){
 System.out.println("Yes found");
 }
 else{
 System.out.println("Not Found");
 }
}
```

`it` is the iterator reference object and `al` is the ArrayList reference object.

the search is always return Not found but the element what I find is exist. How to fix it in order to return FOUND? Please help me with the appropriate code Thank's.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use `List#contains`.

Comment: Besides the "dont compare strings using ==" you also might look into defining proper equals and hashCode methods within your Product class; that would allow you to use the various "lookup" methods that Java collections offer to you.

Comment: It's not only string comparing - it's also comapring `Pro` with `String`.

Comment: I think it.next() will give you 'Pro' object. You need to get name from Pro object and then compare.

Comment: Post an [MCVE] including the declaration and initialization of  `al`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
ArrayList<Pro> al=new ArrayList<Pro>();
    Iterator<Pro> it=al.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
         if(it.next().getName().equals( name)){
         System.out.println("Yes found");
         }
         else{
         System.out.println("Not Found");
         }
    }
```

Comment: Typecasting of it.next() will be required here

Comment: @Jeet No, variable it is parameterized.

Comment: @barsik Correct, I missed that.